# Regular FatalThrowableError in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php in Symfony 2.8 project

Tags: php, symfony, caching, symfony-2.8

I get the following error regularly:

> FatalThrowableError in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 8205:
>   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable
>   (T_VARIABLE)

When I look at the code in my dev cache I can see a random `?` prefixing a typehint.

Where is this coming from? Why does it happen?

The only solution seems to be hard deleting my cache.

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function __construct(?\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher = null)
{
    static $reflection;
```

Comment: That's a "PHP 7 thing": it's a way to define `nullable` (not optional!) argument. Don't know why your cache produces it

Comment: I am running PHP 7 on my server. I don't know why this is an issue.

Comment: Are you sure that your `CLI` and webserver, (don't know when the error is shown) run both the right PHP version?

Comment: My app is running 7.0.8 and CLI is 7.0.12

Comment: Umh, that's weird, ATM I have no clue

Comment: I get it when I move from git branch to git branch. It's really annoying and I don't know what the solution is.